# If an alien race used solid nitrogen hammers as weapons, how long would they last before melting on earth?

Tags: magic, science-fiction

The enemy they fight have an extremely high body temperature, I’m wondering the effects of solid nitrogen would have on them. The idea is the enemies' bodies are like molten under the skin.

Comment: I suspect you'd be better off hosing the enemies down with water, to be honest.

Comment: How about looking up the properties of solid nitrogen first and than come back?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I’ll change the hammers to titanium they have a higher melting point to the other races core temperature

Comment: What you probably want is something with a large specific heat capacity to absorb the most energy from the aliens' bodies. Like Starfish Prime said, water may be best for the job.

Comment: The melting point of solid nitrogen is somewhere around -210C. That is *negative* two hundred. It is *extremely* low - I'd expect a solid nitrogen anything to not last long on Earth where the average temperature (depending on location and season) usually varies somewhere between 0C and 30C. Room temperature is around 18C to 24C. While temperatures can can definitely deviate around the world, it's still nowhere close to -200C.

Comment: First of all, welcome to Worldbuilding.SE. I am a bit puzzled because your title and the body of your text asks for different things, albeit related. You should clarify what you are looking for exactly. You can [edit](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/posts/153485/edit) your post. And generally, you can use the [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7183/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) to check your questions, if you are unsure.

Comment: I don't know how long it would be before the aliens melted, I don't imagine they'd last long if they were adapted to an environment so much colder than ours that nitrogen is solid at room temperature... though I don't know if the aliens would *melt* as opposed to just dying from heatstroke and, yanno, leaving a body behind... the hammers would melt better, though  =)

Answer (score 3):

I think the hot aliens will be protected by the the **Leidenfrost effect.**

[image: Leidenfrost effect]

https://www.engineersedge.com/physics/leidenfrost_effect_13089.htm

> The Leidenfrost effect is a phenomenon in which a liquid, in near
>   conact with a mass significantly hotter than the liquid’s boiling
>   point, produces an insulating vapor layer keeping that liquid from
>   boiling rapidly.  This is most commonly seen when cooking; one
>   sprinkle drops of water in a pan to gauge its temperature: if the
>   pan’s temperarture is at or above the Leidenfrost point , the water
>   skitters across the pan and takes longer to evaporate than n a pan
>   below the temperature of the Leidenfrost point (but still above
>   boiling temperature).  The effect is also responsible for the ability
>   of liquid nitrogen to skitter across floors.

Throwing liquids on your hot folks would have the same effect - a cushion of high pressure vapor would immediately form and this would repel the bulk of the cold substance.  Backyard Scientist on youtube has some great demonstrations of this effect using super cold and super hot materials.

Your cold folks would be better off using hammers of substances with a high thermal mass and very high boiling point.

Comment: But the swinging hammer also has momentum. Wouldn't the net effect be more of an ordinary hammer hitting somebody holding a balloon to their chest?The hammer loses some momentum pushing out the air in the balloon until the opposite sides come in contact, then the rest of the force is transmitted directly to the body. Alongside a possible steam explosion of sorts, as the tip of the hammer hits the body

Comment: @nzaman I buy a "steam" explosion for sure.  The hammer vector will be  countered by the reverse vector force from increasing gas pressure, possibly to the point where the net vector is away from the heat.  It may or may not be possible to hit something very hot with something solid that is very cold.

Comment: Unless they're clever enough to round the end...

Comment: If the surface of the aliens or the hammer are irregular, the Leidenfrost effect will be minimal. Protrusions on the surface in excess of 0.2 mm will penetrate through the protective boundary layer. Second, the hammer is impacting the alien, this is far different than a drop of liquid being supportted by a vapor barrier - you are actively squeezing out the boundary layer during an impact event.

Comment: the Leidenfrost effect can easily be overcome by say swinging the object in question. The effect is only stable on a relatively static surface.